# How to publish a clickonce application and configure with iis7

Tags: vb.net

I have inherited a vb application that was hosted on another server and was accessed through a web page. I need to move it from that server to a server my department supports. We have a web server set up for other apps and are using iis7. I was able to publish the application on our web server, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I tried to publish it in the inetpub/wwwroot directory and access it that way, but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the source? Can you re-run the publish wizard in Visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I have the source and have re-ran the publish wizard to publish on my server. I just don't know how to get iis configured to display the publish.htm to distribute the application.

Comment: You don't have to mess with iis itself. You are trying to make this more complicated than it actually is ;-) . Just run the wizard, specifying where the application files will be located. Then place the html page generated by the wizard into the structure of your website, and the files in the folder you specified.  That's it.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a shared folder on my server. I then run the publish feature in VS with \\myserver\myshare as the path. I selected "From a UNC path or file share" for the How will users install the application? option. This publishes fine on my share. When you say place the html page in the structure of my website, do you mean to remove it from my share and put in the inetpub/wwwroot directory?

Comment: I'm assuming you already have a website, on which you are publishing this? You already said it originally was from a webpage. If not, then just use the wizard-created page as the homepage of a new website.

Comment: Yes we have a default site with two asp.net applications. What I did for those was published them local and moved them to the inetpub/wwwroot folder then converted to an application. This is a different type of application that I've not dealt with, so I'm not sure how to use what is there and display the publish.htm.

Comment: Don't think of the ClickOnce part as an application - the ClickOnce page is just a page from which the application itself is downloaded. Just incorporate the wizard-created page in your existing website, as just another page reached by a link on your homepage. If you've put the correct paths etc into the wizard, your users will be able to navigate to the page, click the 'install' link on there, and the application will automatically download and run. Perhaps this is what you're missing - ClickOnce is a way of deploying locally-running apps, not web apps.

Comment: Thanks peterG, I was able to get it going. I knew it wasn't an application, I was just unsure how to configure iis to display the publish page. I ended up adding my published folder as a new site and put the Default Document as my publish.htm.